# Android ListView OnItemClickListener() issue

Tags: listview, android-studio, onitemclicklistener

I got a porblem,
I want to make a basic message reader app and i have a problem with the
onItemClickListener().

This is the code:
chat_fragment.java

```
 public void onItemClickListener(){
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            TextView tx_title, tx_sender, tx_message;
            tx_sender = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tx_sender);
            tx_title = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tx_title);
            tx_message = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tx_message);

           SENDER = tx_sender.getText().toString();
           TITLE = tx_title.getText().toString();
           MESSAGE = tx_message.getText().toString();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ReadMsg())
                    .commit();
        }

    });}
```

When the app move on to the ReadMSg fragment on there not the selected items data are visible, only the first item  data are visible on there.

There is the ReadMsg() fragment:

```
 View rootview;
TextView title,sender,message;
Chat_Fragment chat_fragment;
Button back_btn;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_read_msg,container,false);
    title=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tw_titlumsg);
    sender=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tw_delamsg);
    message=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tw_mesajemsg);
    title.setText(chat_fragment.TITLE);
    sender.setText(chat_fragment.SENDER);
    message.setText(chat_fragment.MESSAGE);

    //onBackBtnListener();
    return rootview;
}
```

There is a photo about the list:
[image: First Line: Sender, Second Line: Title, Third Line: Message]

First Line: Sender,
Second Line: Title,
Third Line: Message,
I hope i was understandable, and of course i am sorry about my bad english!
Thaks!

Comment: You have to use `Bundle` to pass data in your case. Just `Google` it. You will find how to use it.@László Csiki

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia thanks, i tried, but still not working :(  any else idea?

Comment: Can you give your whole project? So, I can edit it.@László Csiki

Comment: I am sorry, but the whole project is a little big :) What do you need exactly? Which you must work is the two fragment and they layers, no? @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: Let me create an example for you. I will post it very soon.@László Csiki

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it! @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: I have made a project for you. Link is [here](http://pastebin.com/yxQQm4Rv). Although I am unable to manage the `onBackPress()` event on fragments. Please, Let me know for any updates!@László Csiki

Comment: Thanks, i really apreciate it! But you forgeted the Frag_Single_SMS.java. @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: ohh...[here](http://pastebin.com/wDCTZx2V) it is. Is it working?@László Csiki

Comment: Unfortunetly no :( but i created a project for you, could you resolve it? Please! I think it's more complex then you imagine. [Link](http://www113.zippyshare.com/v/wE1Le4Z9/file.html) @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: Ok. Let me check it out.@László Csiki

Comment: Ok, thx :) If you don't understand something just say it :) @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: Could you tell me some good news? @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: Actually I have not seen your code till now. Unfortunately I did not get chance to work on it. I will surely update you soon.@László Csiki

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry, i do not want to disturb you! :) @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: It's ok.@László Csiki

Comment: Any news? @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: No. Sorry for bad news@László Csiki

Comment: It's ok,  doesn't matter. @MaulikM.Dodia